# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined at 507 jquery.validate.js"

Tags: 7, javascript, forms

I am trying to implement clientside validation using the clientside validation model. I have been following the documentation located [here.](https://drupal.org/node/1324772) Specifically the Form API Section for Drupal 7. I believe I have followed the instructions faithfully but when I try it out I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined at 507 jquery.validate.js
```

Here is my slightly modified jquery script I am using:

```
(function ($) {
  //Define a Drupal behaviour with a custom name
  Drupal.behaviors.dynamicTextfieldValidator = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      //Add an eventlistener to the document reacting on the
      //'clientsideValidationAddCustomRules' event.
      $(document).bind('clientsideValidationAddCustomRules', function(event){
          //Add your custom method with the 'addMethod' function of jQuery.validator
          //http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage
          jQuery.validator.addMethod("validInputType", function(value, element, param) {
              return value !== '';
          }, jQuery.format('Field can not be empty'));
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

The code looks right to me but I am no javascript expert. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try closing `Drupal.behaviors.dynamicTextfieldValidator` with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: Is validation loading after jquery? I've had problems with this module due to `function clientside_validation_js_alter()` not referencing $javascript or setting a group, which caused it to load before other scripts.

Comment: I see that jquery.validate.js is being loaded after all the jquery scripts. What I don't see is my validation script being loaded. I am using drupal_add_js() with the correct file path but I still don't see it in the list of scripts being loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the call to drupal_add_js being made? yourmodule_js_alter || yourtheme_js_alter || other?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, caught up in other projects. The call is being made from hook_clientside_validation_rule_alter().

Comment: You're editing the module code directly?!

Comment: No. This is in my module using the hook_clientside_validation_rule_alter().

Comment: Found one similar issue. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847694/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-call-of-undefined-jquery-validate